# Can not authenticate AzureAD after upgrading to .NET 6 from .NET framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, .net-6.0

We have a WinForms application on .NET framework 4.7.2 that use PublicClientApp to acquire token interactively. But after upgrading it to .NET 6 it is giving this error when trying to acquire token interactively

> A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
> Trace ID: 130d2a69-6d73-4281-ad71-0463e72a3b00
> Correlation ID: dd054957-454e-4169-b7f8-f18eeb156836
> Timestamp: 2022-01-26 09:12:01Z'

After looking at this link [microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet](https://github.com/azuread/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications#invalid-client)
 we found a solution that says to enable a Public Client option in the Azure portal. But we already have this option enabled.

.NET 6 uses system browser for interactive authentication but if we try to use embedded browser for authentication by changing TFM suggested here [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#net-5-and-later-use-the-target-framework-moniker-option) then authentication works as expected.

So, is there any way to use system browser for authentication instead of embedded browser or do we need to change any settings in the azure portal for our application to use system browser cause enabling the embedded browser creates a dependency on the OS version?

Comment: Could you please check once that you have provided the correct client id ,tenant id details on your `appsettings.json` and could you please share your `nuget packages` that you are being used

Comment: Yes. I have checked that the client id and tenant id are correct. And I am using these two nuget packages `Microsoft.Identity.Client (4.40.0)` and `Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal (2.19.3)`

Comment: Could you please let us know if you have updated the `nuget packages` or not.

Comment: Initially, I was using these versions `Microsoft.Identity.Client (4.8.2)` and
`Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal (2.7.0-preview)` in .NET framework 4.7.2 and everything was working. But after upgrading to .NET 6 it was not working anymore. So I updated the nuget packages to these versions `Microsoft.Identity.Client (4.40.0)` and
`Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal (2.19.3)` but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To update `.net framework` winforms application to `.net 6` we need to follow the below workaround:

**You need to analyse your app by using `upgrade-assistant analyze` command pass the name of the project that upgrading.**
[image]

Please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation*** for complete setup: [***Upgrade a Windows Forms App to .NET 6 with the .NET Upgrade Assistant***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website)

Comment: We already have followed this approach to upgrade our application to .net 6. After upgrading we are facing this authentication related issue.

Comment: Could you please check the required details are correctly added or not in `appsettings.json` and check the `.csproj` file for the target framework

Comment: Yes. I have checked that the required details are correct in `appsettings.json` and the target framework is `net6-windows` in `.csproj` file

Comment: Could you please check the details in your `appsettings.json` [as per this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#completing-the-upgrade) its contain the in your application or not.

Comment: As I have already mentioned that we were able to authenticate when using embedded browser instead of system browser. All details in `appsettins.json` are correct as we were able to authenticate using an embedded browser. I was looking for a way to use system browser instead of the embedded browser.